# Modifying NSDate to represent 1 month from today

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

I'm adding repeating events to a Cocoa app I'm working on. I have repeat every day and week fine because I can define these mathematically (3600*24*7 = 1 week). I use the following code to modify the date:

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(3600*24*7*(weeks))]
```

I know how many months have passed since the event was repeated but I can't figure out how to make an NSDate object that represents 1 month/3 months/6 months/9 months into the future. Ideally I want the user to say repeat monthly starting Oct. 14 and it will repeat the 14th of every month.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

(Almost the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181459/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-midnight-tomorrow/181495#181495).)

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendarDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Use of NSCalendarDate strongly
>   discouraged. It is not deprecated yet,
>   however it may be in the next major OS
>   release after Mac OS X v10.5. For
>   calendrical calculations, you should
>   use suitable combinations of
>   NSCalendar, NSDate, and
>   NSDateComponents, as described in
>   Calendars in [Dates and Times
>   Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html).

Following that advice:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.month = 1;
NSDate *nextMonth = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options:0];
[components release];

NSDateComponents *nextMonthComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:nextMonth];

NSDateComponents *todayDayComponents = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

nextMonthComponents.day = todayDayComponents.day;
NSDate *nextMonthDay = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nextMonthComponents];

[gregorian release];
```

There may be a more direct or efficient implementation, but this should be accurate and should point in the right direction.

Comment: Is better to use NSDateCompontents and setMonth to +1. Then you get same date but in next month. 
`NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setMonth://here you set current month+1];
NsDate *nextMonth = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
`

Answer (score 22):

Use NSCalender, NSDateComponents and NSDate:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
components.month = 1;
NSDate *oneMonthFromNow = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

Just set the different properties of `components` to get different periods of time (e.g. 3 months, 6 months etc).

Note: Depending on the context, you may want to use `[[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease]` instead of `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]`, if by "1 month" you mean "1 month on the Gregorian calendar".

Comment: I don't have a device to test with right now, but what would happen if you go forward by one month on January 29 if it's not a leap year? Would the day be February 28 or March 1?

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably use NSCalendarDate.

Get current date's dayOfMonth, monthOfYear and yearOfCommonEra, as three numbers.

Add the required number of months (1/3/6/9), taking care of 1) whether that date exist (e.g. 31 April, 29 Feb on a non-leap year), and 2) roll-over of year.

Create that new date with NSCalendarDate's initWithYear:month:day:hour:minute:second:timeZone:

Comment: The documentation makes clear that NSCalendarDate should not be used.

Comment: use of the NSCalendarDate is generally not accepted for iPhone Apps.

Answer (score 0):

**NSCalendarDate** is no longer supported by new SDK , will have problem while building for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the below:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.month = 1;
NSDate *nextMonth = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options:0];
[components release];

NSDateComponents *nextMonthComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:nextMonth];
NSDate *nextMonthDay = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nextMonthComponents];

[gregorian release];
```