# Get date of date + value Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ipad, date

I would like to get a date from an amount of months plus a date.

as an example.

I would like the output to be:

start date: 4th april

amount of months: 5

output date: 4th september

Is there any code to do this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying NSDate to represent 1 month from today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185780/modifying-nsdate-to-represent-1-month-from-today)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a read of Apple's [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i) there are a few solutions that should present themselves.

For example, you could create a base [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDate) and then use the [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCalendar) `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:` method to add the relevant number of months as a component.

If you're after some clean sample source code, see the "Adding Components to a Date" section within the [Calendrical Calculations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html) section of the above programming guide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, have a look at Apple's [Date and Time Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html).