# Auto-renewable subscriptions: How long a month is？

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I got confused about some issues:

1: The one month duration of auto-renewable subscriptions is 30 days or does it depend on a natural month?

Because I can only test in sandbox mode，so the duration is just several minutes...
Maybe Apple just simply calculates it like this:   2013\01\15  -> 2013\02\15 -> 2013\03\15. If so,the second issue comes up

2: For example: I buy a monthly auto-renewable subscriptions at 2013\03\31 ,because 2013\04 only has 30 days, then what is the expires_date of my subscriptions?  2013\04\30 or 2013\05\01 or other date ?

Comment: of course, we can use the  expires_date get from apple to found out the date to verify the receipt, i just want to konw the rule apple used to calculate the expires_date!!

Answer (score 5):

It's adding 1 month, not 30 days.  The number of days in 1 month varies.  So purchasing a subscription on 3/31 would end on 4/30.

You can use NSDate, NSCalendar, and NSDateComponents to add a month to a date and see how long it will last.  More info here: [Modifying NSDate to represent 1 month from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185780/modifying-nsdate-to-represent-1-month-from-today)

Comment: Thanks.BTW,i just know that: in Lunar calendar, 2013 has 355 days, 2014 has 383... amazing

Comment: Let's imagine that we have 10 subscription purchases on 30th, and next month has 31 days. When will they renew? On 30th, or on 31st? :)

Comment: I think I covered this in my answer :)

Comment: Does this mean an app with auto renewal subscriptions can expect less sales on the 31st of a month because there will be no monthly renewals being processed? Assuming of course new subscriptions remains consistent. And of course excluding august as its previous month also has 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this from my own app's data on both iOS and Android.

If someone purchases a monthly renewing subscription on, for example, the 15th of one month, then it will renew on the 15th of the next month, irrespective of how many days were in the month.

If someone purchases the subscription on the 31st of March,  then it will renew on May 1st (because April has no 31st day, the renewal date will jump to the next available day in the calendar year - this also applies to February in a leap year, etc).

Given this, and assuming your app's primary income is from subscriptions, over time you should expect to see lower than average sales on the 31st of any given month because there won't be as many renewals. But it is no cause for concern as it is counteracted by the fact that you should expect to see higher than average sales on the 1st of any month that follows a long month anyway. Don't be dissapointed if you check your stats on the 31st of any month.