# Duration of auto-renewable at IAP

Tags: ios, xcode, duration, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

How can I know about duration of auto-renewable subscription between purchase-date and expire-date.

For example, If user has purchased 1 month product by auto-renewable in 31 Jan, when is expire day? (28 Feb?…If leap year?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Auto-renewable subscriptions ： How long a month is？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411408/auto-renewable-subscriptions-how-long-a-month-is).

If you're still curious, you can confirm by checking the `expires_date` field, which is in the `receipt` field of the JSON object that holds the parsed information from the receipt (in the production, not sandbox, environment). More at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html

Comment: Thank you Joshua C. Lerner :)