# Unexplained crash with NSTimeInterval

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I cant seem to figure out a bug with a piece of code change that is causing a hard crash in my app without much of a debugging trail.

Here is the original method

```
+ (NSArray *)currentReservations {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    double futureTimeframe = interval + SecondsIn24Hours;
    NSArray *reservations = [Reservation findWithSql:@"select * from Reservation where timestamp < ? and timestamp > ?" withParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:ceil(futureTimeframe)], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:floor(interval)], nil]];
    return reservations;
}
```

The method sets a few variables so I can query the database to find all records that have timestamps between now and 24 hours into the future.  I need to change the method to query for all records with timestamps between now and tomorrow (midnight of the next day), so I updated the code to this based on [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181459/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-midnight-tomorrow)

```
+ (NSArray *)currentReservations {
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setDay:1];  // tomorrow
    NSDate *tomorrow = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options:0];
//    [components release];  // dont think we need this release, but it is in the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181459/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-midnight-tomorrow
    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:tomorrow];
    [components setHour:0];
    [components setMinute:0];
    NSDate *tomorrowMidnight = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
    [components release], components=nil;
    [gregorian release], gregorian=nil;


    NSTimeInterval interval = [today timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval tomorrowInterval = [tomorrowMidnight timeIntervalSince1970];

    NSArray *reservations = [Reservation findWithSql:@"select * from Reservation where timestamp < ? and timestamp > ?" withParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tomorrowInterval], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:floor(interval)], nil]];
    return reservations;
}
```

However, when these two lines:

```
    NSTimeInterval interval = [today timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval tomorrowInterval = [tomorrowMidnight timeIntervalSince1970];
```

are included the app crashes.  I've narrowed it down to these two lines by commenting them out, etc..

I'm completely at a loss for what is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "the app crashes"?  In what way?  What stack trace do you get?

Comment: when running in the simulator just a hard crash to main loop

Comment: you need to get a backtrace (type bt in the debug console), "crashes" isn't going to help anyone solve your problem

Comment: Oh, and you do need that commented out release, or you're leaking the original `components` allocation.

Comment: here is the backtrace: https://gist.github.com/4cedf2cef066a3a57cb6

Comment: Hmm, that's not very helpful (to me anyway). I can't help but think that your crash is because of what comes back from your findWithSQL rather than the time interval lines - if you comment these lines out I guess you aren't getting anything back, so no crash. I can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted, the findWithSQL: bit which isn't something I'm familiar with so my suspicions naturally fall on that. If you set a breakpoint and step through with the debugger, you might get more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your crash stack trace is in objc_msgSend inside _CFAutoreleasePoolPop, you can deduce that it's probably an over-release bug.

This line is wrong:

```
[components release], components=nil;
```

You don't own components there. Look at the name of the method that gave it to you.  You are over-releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

As rob mayoff said, the second release is wrong (while the first one is necessary). Try this instead:

```
+ (NSArray *)currentReservations {
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    [components setDay:1];  // tomorrow
    NSDate *tomorrow = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options:0];
    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:tomorrow];
    [components setHour:0];
    [components setMinute:0];
    NSDate *tomorrowMidnight = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
    [gregorian release], gregorian=nil;


    NSTimeInterval interval = [today timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval tomorrowInterval = [tomorrowMidnight timeIntervalSince1970];

    NSArray *reservations = [Reservation findWithSql:@"select * from Reservation where timestamp < ? and timestamp > ?" withParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tomorrowInterval], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:floor(interval)], nil]];
    return reservations;
}
```